# sprite hit a wall or another sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i am trying to understand how to implement the physics of sprite when it hit a wall.
lets say i have a wall, and a sprite is is hitting the wall with velocity and gravity using box2d(cocos2d), what is the simplest way to apply a physics of what happen next to the hit, regrading the velocity,gravity,angle of collision, etc ? contact listener ? do i have to calculate what happen next by my self and apply a new speed and force to the body ??
or box2d does it for me ?

any direction would be great.
thanx.

Comment: There are examples of using box2d coming with cocos2d. Take a look at them

Answer (score 1):

box2d calculates everthing for you. You don't have to worry about what happens after two bodies collide.

If your body hits ground it will bounce as its natural response. You dont have to apply a new force opposite to the gravity. All calculations are done by box2d physics engine. Physics engines are made for that.

In addition to this, if you want you can apply your own forces or impulses like below. It is up to you.

```
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(100, 200);
yourBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, yourBodyDefinition.position);
```

Comment: thanks, i know how to apply force, but what should i do to let box2d calculate what happen next to collision? lets, say i detect collision, whats next ? contact listener do it by it self ??? can you give me example ?

Comment: You have to do nothing. Just create a world with gravity vector. After that set edges of your world and create your bodies. 

In your 'init' method schedule a 'tick' method to be called continueously. In this 'tick' method call 'step' method on your world and update your sprites with calculated box2d physics engine values.

Comment: its not right. i have created a world and 2 sprite are moving in it and in the tick method i call step, and when sprite 1 is arriving to sprite 2, it just overlap him and they continue to move as nothing happen. I DO need to do something , and except detecting collision i just can find out WHAT  ???

Comment: Box2d automatically generate collision response. So in this case certainly your body does not collide.